# How to get country code from storefront in Swift with StoreKit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit

When I tried to get the country code from the storefront with the code snippet below `nil` always get returned.

`StoreKit` has been imported as well as the "In-App Purchase" capability has been added.

Tried to test it in both Simulator and real device with DEBUG and RELEASE setting all get the same result, `nil`.

```
if let storeFront = SKPaymentQueue.default().storefront {
    print("Storefront", storeFront.countryCode)
} else {
    print("Storefront nil")
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/3182430-storefront